# Having trouble figuring out how to write a straightforward SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble figuring out how to write an `SQL` statement...

Let's say I have two tables:

**Projects**

[image: Projects]

**and Tasks**

[image: Tasks]

I'm trying to come up with an SQL statement that returns a unique list of projects and their associated tasks grouped together by commas like this...

[image: Projects With Tasks]

If I need to create a separate table (e.g. Projects_Tasks) for a many-to-many relationship, I'm fine with that, but I'm still not sure what SQL statements would generate that final table.

Comment: Search this site for `[mysql] group_concat`.

Comment: what determines the order of tasks in "Task 1, Task 4, Task 5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.ProjectId, p.Name, t.Tasks
FROM Projects p
JOIN (
SELECT ProjectId,GROUP_CONCAT(Name) as Tasks
FROM Tasks
GROUP BY ProjectId) as t
ON t.ProjectId = p.ProjectId;
```

Comment: You are welcome. if you need more help please tell me and Ill glad to update the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to JOIN the Tasks table to the Projects table, then group the results by Project ID. This allows you to use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to concatenate the task names

```
SELECT Projects.Name, group_concat(Tasks.Name separator ', ') 
      FROM Projects 
      join Tasks 
      on Projects.id = Tasks.projectId 
      group by Tasks.projectId
```